# What does "severability" mean in the following context?

Tags: contract-law, new-york-state, legal-terms

Parties A and B signed a contract governed by New York law. There were three ["conditions precedent"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_precedent) for the contract to take place.None of these conditions precedent had been fulfilled on the signing date, but the contract gave the parties a customary seven days to "true" these conditions.

Seven days passed and the three conditions precedent remained unfulfilled. There is a "severability" clause in the contract. The text reads "If one or more provisions of this agreement is found unenforceable under applicable law, the balance of the agreement shall be interpreted as if such provision were excluded, and shall be enforceable in accordance with its terms."

Does the lack of fulfillment of the "conditions precedent" mean that there is no contract? Or does "severability" mean that the rest of the contract is enforceable even though the key terms and preconditions have not been met?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A severability clause means that any clause in the contract which is itself illegal, or which would make the contract illegal, or otherwise cannot be enforced according to the relevant law, is instead excluded from the contract as if it didn't exist.

This is an extremely common clause, especially where the contract is used in the same form across multiple jurisdictions. The law of these jurisdictions may differ e.g. in the ability for consumers to opt out of class action against harmful effects or for companies to provide no guarantee of longevity in a product.

This clause **does not** change the prerequisites, requirements, rights or obligations under the contract. The conditions must still be met for the remaining terms to have force.

Comment: ...unless, I presume, the prerequisite was, or became, illegal? In which case the clause which requires it would be severed?

Comment: @CCTO: No, the preconditions were perfectly legal the whole time.

Comment: From what I understand (correct me if I'm wrong) a severability clause means that the contract should be treated as though an illegal clause didn't exist *when doing so would be reasonably consistent with the intent of the contract*, but doesn't rule out the possibility that the contract may be voided.  For example, if Bob agrees to pay Joe $10,000/month in exchange for which he will receive 100kg of some substance, but the government bans the sale of such substance, it would be unreasonable to void Joe's obligation to produce the substance without also voiding...

Comment: ...Bob's obligation to pay $10,000/month.

Comment: A contract for the sale of a substance, when that sale is illegal, is itself illegal and totally void. There's no need to consider each obligation separately voided. Anything changing hands would be considered a gift, because there is no contract under which its ownership was transferred and thus no cause for its return under some legally unfair use of the contract, and its return could not be enforced by civil suit. @supercat

Comment: @Nij: Perhaps the example was over-simplified.  Suppose the contract was for 100kg of substance X and 100kg of substance Y, for a combined price of $10,000/month, and only X was prohibited.  If nothing in the contract would indicate the relative worth of X and Y, and no subsequent agreement can be reached on that point, the entire contract may need to be voided even if the sale of Y would otherwise be perfectly legal.

Comment: @supercat The far more typical scenario would be that you were selling a legal 100kg of a substance X for $10,000 and had a penalty interest clause for late payments of 60% per annum interest, even though usury laws capped penalty interest at 45%. The illegal interest clause could be severed from the otherwise valid contract. Or a contract might say it can only be modified in writing even though such clauses are void as a matter of law in your jurisdiction (as they are in CO). This wouldn't invalidate the larger contract, just this term. But you need an underlying completely legal transaction.

Comment: The contract is still valid if the exchange of substance X is excluded. Jurisdictions might sever that and maintain the rest of the deal, or declare the whole thing void and criminal because $Policy. It might be a really bad deal to pay that much money for that amount of substance Y, but that's the risk taken when entering illegal contracts, no? @supercat

Comment: @Nij: The intention with my scenario is that at the time the contract was entered into, both substances were legal, but one of them subsequently became illegal.  If the buyer would have been willing to pay $9,000/month for the X alone but only $2,000 for the Y alone, and the seller would have been willing to sell the specified X alone for only $2,000/month but would not have been willing to sell the Y for less than $9,000, the equitable outcome would be to dissolve the contract entirely and either renegotiate the price of Y or decide no mutually-agreeable price would be possible.

Comment: At that point you'd be looking at a renegotiation of the contract, or an arbitration/civil suit for a judgement on the contract. These things don't happen in a vacuum - both parties would surely be well aware of potential or upcoming changes in regulation, and include terms accordingly (if they have any sense, that is).