What is the current state of U.S. law regarding misleading inducements in shadow banning?
The general idea appears to be that social media companies retain the right to deamplify users' voices, for reasons that may or may not be ethical or sensible. The question is whether users have any remedies arising from the deception often entailed in shadowbanning, where such companies essentially lull users into investing time, money, and effort (in e.g., building an online presence) in projects whose success such companies deliberately defeat without notice.

This is probably a duplicate question, but rather than locate the prior questions I have just answered it.

Related https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/89219/are-social-media-tos-invalid-because-lack-of-due-process-and-mutuality-creates-a


The question is whether users have any remedies arising from the
deception often entailed in shadowbanning, where such companies
essentially lull users into investing time, money, and effort (in
e.g., building an online presence) in projects whose success such
companies deliberately defeat without notice.

Users have no remedies in this situation. Any rights they might have had were waived in the terms of service (which are usually binding). As noted in this Law.SE answer:

Some U.S. states, including Florida and Missouri, have passed laws
that require that certain standards of content moderate be applied.
The U.S. Supreme Court recently remanded those cases to lower courts
for reconsideration of their validity under a more strict legal
standard and in a different legal framework than was previously
required in the case of Murphy v. Missouri (June 26, 2024).

In Murphy, the U.S. Supreme Court strongly implied that such laws would often constitute unconstitutional restrictions on the freedom of speech of the private internet service providing company. The decision, also called the Netchoice case (after a companion case involving Florida and Texas laws) is explored here.

Sorry, I don't understand how discussions of the First Amendment or content moderation are relevant to deceptive inducement. But thank you for taking a stab at it.

@RayWoodcock The Courts have recognized that social media companies have a First Amendment right to deamplify users' voices, for reasons that may or may not be ethical or sensible, without government intervention. Imposing fraud liability would violate those rights of social media companies in this situation. Users of social media sites, in contrast, do not have First Amendment rights with respect to their use of social media sites since social media sites aren't governments.

Thanks again. I'd be open to citations on the issue of deceptive inducement specifically. My apologies otherwise for posing my question here. The net four unexplained downvotes certainly convey that I shouldn't have.

@RayWoodcock Deceptive inducement is not a recognized legal theory in this context. This legal theory fails to state a claim upon which relief can be granted.

@RayWoodcock Hard to see how there's a deceptive inducement when the service provider discloses that it may engage in this conduct and the user consents to it.
