Corporate Law - Loss of Reputation
Organization A and Organization B sign a contract.
Organization A doesn't disclose a certain policy to Organization B and doesn't post this policy anywhere.
Organization B breaks this undisclosed policy which leads to Organization A to cancel the contract.
Organization B suffers economic / brand damages as a result of this cancellation.
Can Organization B sue Organization A for damages / negligance?

Did the contract give A the right to cancel it for the stated reason, or did A breach the contract by doing so?

This sounds like a back door way to trying to find liability for getting kicked off of a social media site, duplicating a prior question. https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/89219/are-social-media-tos-invalid-because-lack-of-due-process-and-mutuality-creates-a

The contract did not state a cancellation clause in it, simply the offer from both parties and the acceptance.

Cancellation
You say that Organization A "cancels" the contract, suggesting that this was a right that Organization A held (perhaps with conditions, such as notice, termination fee, return of goods, etc.). If that is the case, and as long as Organization A did not represent that whatever Organization B was doing would not lead to cancellation of the contract, Organization B's only recourse is to recover whatever the contract says Organization B is owed in the case of cancellation by Organization A.
Breach
If instead, by "cancel" you mean "breach" (as in, Organization A simply stops fulfilling its obligations under the contract), then Organization B has all the ordinary remedies for breach of contract.
Loss of reputation
Loss of reputation is part of what can be recovered for breach of contract, as long as it falls within the ordinary principles for recovery: i.e. increased reputation would have been expected had the contract been performed; and the loss of reputation a was foreseeable outcome of the breach. See e.g. Thomas Management Limited v. Alberta (Minister of Environmental Protection), 2006 ABCA 303, para. 18.
Negligence
The elements of negligence are not made out by the facts as described.

Another thing i forgot to mention was that Org A knew of this policy but chose / forgot not to disclose it to Org B. That is why I'm thinking there may be negligence involved.
Additionally, there was no cancellation clause to the contract just an agreement and payment of services to be delivered.
Organization B was expecting these services in order to deliver promises to their customers and Organization A stopped them without notice.
